# Any efficient way to "strip" a list of items?

Tags: python, list

By "strip" I don't mean strip for each item, I mean remove items, for instance,

```
a = [None, "a", "b", "c", None, None, None]
b = ["4", "4", "a", "b", "c", "4", "4"]
c = ["4", "4", "a", "4", "b", "c", "4", "4"]
```

what I want to keep is

```
["a", "b", "c"] # for the first two
["a", "4", "b", "c"] # for the last one
```

by such a method or function,

```
a.strip(None)  # or strip(a, None)   
b.strip("4")  # or strip(b, "4")
```

I think I can do it using a for loop with a flag to detect the two ends, but I thought it may be not pythonic.

Comment: Is it supposed to operate like `str.strip`, where it only removes from the ends, or should it remove internal values? That is, what does stripping `None` from `[None, 1, None, 2, None]` produce?

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the question. Thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: @Lerner I'm still not exactly sure what you want. Do you want to have the behavior of `str.strip()`? Or do you want to remove all instances of your value from the list?

Comment: It's just like the strip method of str but for the list items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no built-in functionality for this. But there are about a million different ways to handle it. I would suggest using [itertools.dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) on the original list, reverse the result, and do it again:

```
# import the dropwhile function from the itertools module
from itertools import dropwhile

# create a function for this operation
def striplist(l, rem):

        # first, iterate over the list forwards, removing leading occurrences
        # dropwhile returns an iterator, so convert the result to a list
        l = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == rem, l))
        # then reverse it and do it again to strip the trailing occurrences
        l = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == rem, l[::-1]))

        return l[::-1] # return the result back in the original order

a = [None, "a", "b", "c", None, None, None]
b = ["4", "4", "a", "b", "c", "4", "4"]
c = ["4", "4", "a", "4", "b", "c", "4", "4"]

print(striplist(a, None))
print(striplist(b, "4"))
print(striplist(c, "4"))
```

The result:

> ['a', 'b', 'c']
>   ['a', 'b', 'c']
>   ['a', '4', 'b', 'c']

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to generate a new list which has the items at beginning removed. Then you could just loop while last item on the list is one that you want to remove and delete it:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def lstrip(l, item=None):
    l = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == item, l))
    while l and l[-1] == item:
        del l[-1]

    return l

a = [None, "a", "b", "c", None, None, None]
b = ["4", "4", "a", "b", "c", "4", "4"]
c = ["4", "4", "a", "4", "b", "c", "4", "4"]

print(lstrip(a))
print(lstrip(b, '4'))
print(lstrip(c, '4'))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', '4', 'b', 'c']
```

Above will run in **O(n)** time. If you don't care about the performance you could just replace `dropwhile` with another while loop that will delete items from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the `pop()` method of lists to remove anything that matches `item` from the beginning and end of the list.

```
a = [None, "a", "b", "c", None, None, None]
b1 = ["4", "4", "a", "b", "c", "4", "4"]
b2 = ["4", "4", "a", "4", "b", "c", "4", "4"]

def strip(l, item=None):
    while l[0] == item:
        l.pop(0)
    while l[-1] == item:
        l.pop()
    return l

print(strip(a))
print(strip(b1,'4'))
print(strip(b2,'4'))
```

running it produces the requested output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', '4', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the behavior of the strip function but for lists, I'd recommend the following solution:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile

def strip(item, lst):
  tmp = list(dropwhile(lambda el: el == item, lst))
  tmp =  list(dropwhile(lambda el: el == item, tmp[::-1]))
  return tmp
```

This works by first stripping every occurrence of `item` from the *left* side of `lst`. We then flip the list around and, by doing so, strip every occurrence of `item` from the *right* side of the list. We finally flip the list back around again to its original ordering and return the list.

Answer (score -1):

List comprehension would be more fast and convenient way
Since its one line there is no need to have separate function

```
a =  [elem for elem in a if elem != None]
b =  [elem for elem in b if elem != '4']
```

Though if you insist on a function you could simply wrap this in function

```
def strip(l, item):
  return [i for i in l if i != item]
```

Comment: This is not how strip is supposed to work, your code will remove `None` and `'4'` in the middle of the list.

Answer (score -2):

You need to do something  like this:

```
list=['a',4,4,4]
def strip(list,no):
    while (1):
        try:
            del list[list.index(no)]
        except:
            break
    return list
print strip(list,4)
```

Comment: Firstly, this will delete all instances of the given item, not just the ones at the ends. Secondly, it's bad practice to mask a built-in like `list`. Thirdly, finding an item's index and then using `del` means you should be using the list's `remove` method instead.